# Automating Azure FrontDoor Managed Certificate Renewal for Custom Domains with CNAME chain

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

## Init

I have an Azure Front Door instance with web application firewall policies and Azure-managed certificates. My setup involves custom domains on Azure Front Door, but it requires that no CNAME is pointing directly to Azure Front Door. Instead, I have a CNAME record for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) that points to a delegated zone, specifically [www.production.example.com](http://www.production.example.com). This delegated zone allows the application to migrate seamlessly without requiring any direct interaction from the primary zone's DNS owner.

This situation leads to the issue described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/787131/domain-validation-steps-for-azure-front-door-stand, where the certificate re-validation fails, but the TXT validation works correctly. As a result, I have to manually regenerate the TXT challenge on the Front Door and update the records to renew the certificates every few months.

## Question

I would like to automate the renewal process of TLS certificates with Azure FrontDoor Managed Certificates. I plan to set up a pipeline that runs periodically. When a custom domain is in a 'pending' state, I intend to use PowerShell or Azure CLI to trigger the regeneration of the 'dnsauth' value. After generating the new value, I will retrieve and update the corresponding DNS TXT record. However, I'm unable to find an endpoint or method to automate the regeneration of the TXT '_dnsauth' record as I can manually do it in the portal.
[Azure Portal custom domain regenerate ownership _dnsauth TXT record in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GafRm.png)

Does anyone have information on how to achieve this or any suggestions on how to automate this process?

## What I have tested so far

I have gone through the documentation and tried Google, but have not found such an endpoint/method so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Azure CLI command:  [az afd custom-domain regenerate-validation-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/custom-domain?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-custom-domain-regenerate-validation-token)